# Mac OS X shell utility that shows individual cpu usage in multi-core systems

Tags: macos, terminal, multicore, cpu-usage, utilities

I've been looking for a osx utility that shows cpu usage for each cpu. For example
 CPU 0 - 10%
 CPU 1 -  2%
 ...

I know of many ways of getting this information in other Unix-like system (/proc, mpstat, etc) but none work in osx. The most useful one for Mac is top but it only shows total cpu usage. I need the application to be run from the shell so that I can log the usage over time. I also tried cpuwalk.d but it only shows you if the application is running in one or more cores.

If you take a look at Activity Monitor app you will notice that it basically displays the same info as top, but with the addition of a graph that shows cpus load.

If anyone has any idea of how to get the information I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: This is a better question for Super User or Apple.SE.

Answer (score 13):

You can try htop. If you have homebrew installed, simple install it via "brew install htop", after the installation finished, type in htop on the shell.

Comment: htop doesn't seem to show this information. I right now have my MBP fan on at full speed due to the brew upgrade, and yet I see all processes at 0% (sorted by CPU%).

Comment: you need to run htop as root, otherwise you won't get per-process cpu usage info.

so run "sudo htop"

Answer (score 0):

you can download os x hardware monitor src from: https://github.com/max-horvath/htop-osx